# BigQuery - Illegal Escape Sequence

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having an issue matching regular expression in BigQuery. I have the following line of code that tries to identify user agents:

```
when regexp_contains((cs_user_agent),  '^AppleCoreMedia\/1\.(.*)iPod') then "iOS App - iPod"
```

However, BigQuery doesn't seem to like escape sequences for some reason and I get this error that I can't figure out:

```
Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \/ at [4:63]
```

This code works fine in a regex validator I use, but BigQuery is unhappy with it and I can't figure out why. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `regexp_contains((cs_user_agent),  r'^AppleCoreMedia\/1\.(.*)iPod')`

Comment: Could you please explain what the 'r' does?

Comment: The r means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored. ... "String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences. You can "google" this for more info :o)